# strange behaviour of java

Tags: java, javascript

I have a form named `abc` with multiple dropdown elements named as `splitOption`.html of this element is something like this-

```
<select title="Split Delivery for EO2135VX" name="splitOption"  onchange="splitDelivery('2','trId2',this.value,'5000','N',this,0,'DIST');"> 
    <option value="" selected=""></option>
    <option value="2">Split 2 deliveries</option>
    <option value="3">Split 3 deliveries</option>
    <option value="4">Split 4 deliveries</option>
    <option value="5">Split 5 deliveries</option>
</select>
```

When I submit the form and try to get this value in my controller by this code

```
String[] arrSplitOption = request.getParameterValues("splitOption");
```

It gives me `arrSplitOption = null` in my logs, **this issue is only in mozila**, it's working fine in IE. 
I tried to alert the `splitOption length` just before submitting the form, it gave me correct value.
I don't know what's going wrong.
can any body tell me what could be the reason behind this.

Comment: compare html generated by both. generally it is IE not the FF

Comment: Please add the URL / body parameters for requests submitted via IE & Mozilla - this is very unlikely to be a Java issue. Also, what Servlet engine are you using?

Comment: @jigar joshi- yes that's y i have written it as a strange

Comment: both are generating same html

Comment: I'd look into that JavaScript function `splitDelivery` since this is a browser specific problem. Seems like it is behaving differently in different browsers. You might want to include that code here too.

Comment: it's a very long code, have multiple of validations, as i said in my question, i am getting exact length of splitOption element `just before form submit`. so i don't think so that there is any problem in that function.

Comment: @vivek The HTTP requests generated on submission of the form will vary - as @laz suggests it's likely to be a Javascript bug. Use FireBug to review the actual data sent to the browser.

Comment: you can see `splitDelivery` code here- http://jsfiddle.net/FCkzP/

Comment: it's just adding no of row below the another row

Comment: @johnstok - how can i see what data has been sent in fire-bug

Comment: hmmm, data is not being send, but it's under my form and i am submitting my form without any error then why it's not coming...ohhhh god wierd java script ...please tell me what could be wrong here

Comment: i resolved this issue..so please close this question

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] arrSplitOption = request.getParameterValues("splitOption");
```

That shouldn't work unless you have `multiple="multiple"` in the `<select/>`. There'd be no reason for it return more than a single string without multiselect enabled on the select.

Comment: i have multiple dropdown list with name `splitOption` in my form, and this code is working in IE

Comment: and it's not a multiselect dropdown list

Comment: Your example didn't have the multiple attribute in it.